# How to create a wix DirectoryCombo element that only shows network shares?

Tags: directory, wix, network-share

The wix `DirectoryCombo` element has the attributes `Remote` and `Fixed`. By setting the `Remote` attribute to `no`, network shares are removed from the drop down list created by this element. Likewise, setting the `Fixed` attribute to `no` results in a list which excludes local drives. My problem is that I can't restrict the list to only show network shares. If `Remote` is set to `yes` and `Fixed` is set to `no`, I expect the drop down list to do what I want, i.e. only show network shares. But the default entry in that list always shows the property value its `Property` attribute is assigned to.

Is there a way to prevent this default entry from showing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can prevent this by setting anyone of the network drive value to that **DirectoryCombo** Property before run that dialog. Write a custom action to read the network drives and set any one of the drive value to that Directory property and schedule the custom action in InstallUISequence.

```
[CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult CustomAction1(Session session)
    {       
        DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
        foreach (DriveInfo drvInfo in drives)
        {
            if (drvInfo.DriveType == DriveType.Network)
            {
                session["SHARED_DRIVE"] = drvInfo.Name;
                break;
            }
        }
        return ActionResult.Success;
    }

  <Binary Id="SharedDrive" SourceFile="TestProject.CA.dll" />
  <CustomAction Id="SHAREDDRIVE" BinaryKey="SharedDrive" DllEntry="CustomAction1" Return="check" />

 <InstallUISequence>
     <Custom Action="SHAREDDRIVE" After="AppSearch">Not Installed</Custom>
 </InstallUISequence>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Just to make it clear for people who don't know how to use this code: The last thing you have to do is to reference the public `SHARED_DRIVE` variable in the `DirectoryCombo` element like so:
`<Control Id="DirectoryComboControl" X="21" Y="52" Width="200" Height="100" Type="DirectoryCombo" Property="SHARED_DRIVE" Fixed="no" Remote="yes" />`